# No exception logged in async task

Tags: c#, async-await, task, worker

I found a lot of similar posts, but none outlining the problem i had specifically.

I have a C# Worker project. In the `StartAsync` method of the worker, i call `await TryConnect();`
TryConnect looks like this:

```
private async Task TryConnect()
{
        Logging.Log("1");
        var startResult = await StartUserStreamAsync();

        Logging.Log("2");
        if (!startResult.Success)
        {
            Logging.Log("3");
            throw new Exception($"Failed to start: {startResult.Error}");
        }
        listenKey = startResult.Data;
        Logging.Log("4");
}
```

Calling site looks like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
        //initialize
        await Initialize();            
        ///other code
}

private async Task Initialize()
{
        ///other code
        await TryConnect();
        ///other code
}
```

As you can probably guess. 1, 2 and 3, are logged in console.
However, 4 isn't, and the exception is thrown.

In previous normal fully sync console applications. This just throws an uncaught exception, the application stops execution, and all is as i expect it to be. I do not intend to recover from that state.
However in async land, it stays silent. No exception is thrown, nothing to indicate anything is wrong except execution of the calling method seems to halt.

Why is this, and what should i be doing? Am i forced to try/catch it, and if so, what if you forget? Are you just left to figure out your not so obvious mistake?

Comment: how are you calling `TryConnect`?

Comment: As stated in the question: await TryConnect();
This is itself inside an Async Task method, and that is inside the async Task ExecuteAsync method from the worker, also properly awaited there.

Comment: The exception is propagated when the worker stops (i.e. `StopAsync` is called on the `BackgroundService` class).
What behavior would you expect? The whole `BackgroundService` or rather hosted services in general is build around the .NET hosting model where you don't typically want to crash the application even if one of the hosted services fails. Whether this makes sense for you really depends on the application you're attempting to build.

Comment: I expected the same/similar behavior as normal console applications. I might be in over my head on the whole async worker thing. Documentation is all but clear about what my expectations _should_ be for stuff that i am used to working a specific way for a decade.

I guess the question now becomes "What do you do instead of throwing an exception if you just want the code to implode on itself if this were to fail?"

Comment: In reality that async call StartUserStreamAsync goes into a library, so no can do there, i have no clue.

Comment: You are comparing synchronous Console applications with asynchronous Worker services. By changing two parameters of the problem at once, you end up in a situation that you can't make safe conclusions. IMHO you should either compare synchronous vs asynchronous Console apps, or Console app vs Worker service (both asynchronous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async aspect of the code you posted is correct and works as expected.

However, since you are working with a Worker, assumptions from other application types do not hold.

As the worker is implemented through a `BackgroundService`, the `ExecuteAsync` method only causes failures when it throws synchronously. This is interpreted as an error during service start-up.

Once `ExecuteAsync` suspends (first await that does actual asynchronous work is encountered), the `BackgroundService` assumes that normal service work is now in progress and that it is started successfully. After that, the service is assumed to be running.

Once the service is shut down (e.g. by being stopped in the service manager, `sudo systemctl stop` etc.), it will trigger the cancellation token passed to `ExecuteAsync` and await the returned `Task`. At this point, it would encounter the exception you expect.

My understanding is that services should not require user interaction, they should just keep doing whatever they do, being resilient to any possible errors in their process, reporting any errors to corresponding OS facilities (e.g. EventLog). As such, any code that is done in `ExecuteAsync` should be wrapped in appropriate try/catch, possibly except the `OperationCanceledException` thrown from the cancellation token on shutdown.

If, at some point, you realize the service can no longer function, you can terminate the hosting process through `IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-hosting-ihostapplicationlifetime-stopapplication))

If you require asynchronous work during start-up, it is possible to implement your worker as `IHostedService` directly and implement the `StartAsync` method as you see fit.

See also [BackgroundService source on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs) for reference. Microsoft Docs also has [Implement the IHostedService interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/timer-service) tutorial.

I can also suggest reading up on [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) as this is the underlying infrastructure that manages the worker `BackgroundService`. There's quite a bit on host lifecycle and related concepts.

Comment: Thanks for this. So besides doing the startup specifically in StartAsync, if i at any point encounter a critical error. The correct way would be to throw the exception, and then just StopApplication directly after? Or just leave the exception out it altogether, log my error directly through logging and then StopApplication?

Comment: From my very limited experience, I can recommend creating a clear picture of what those critical errors are and how these should be handled. Do you want the service to restart? Do you want an e-mail sent? Based on that, experiment with a simple version of your service that only fails with such error until you are happy with the resulting behavior in context of the OS facilities as those cannot be easily changed.

Comment: All in all, I still think that not stopping the service from within would generally be a better approach but I don't know anything about what you're trying to do.

Comment: For some context, i am writing something for home use only, to run within docker on my little NAS at home. The only reason i got here, was because of the docker requirement, and the library requiring async as well. It will just sit there and consume/react to a stream of data from a server.

If this thing fails to start, i want it to scream what killed it, and just keel over. There is little point in retrying a reconnect on the fact that i passed it the wrong login credentials or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for providing more details. I agree with your thinking and I think that implementing IHostedService directly and validating the state (and possibly crashing) in StartAsync would be most natural.

Answer (score 2):

I have blog posts describing both the [silent failure](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-silent-failure.html) and [application lifetime](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/backgroundservice-gotcha-application-lifetime.html) issues. In summary, even though both behaviors are surprising, they are both by design.

In my own code, I use a `CriticalBackgroundServiceBase` type that derives from `BackgroundService`, and ensures exceptions are logged (rather than ignored) and that when the service ends the application ends.